# What does the "Grant easy access" feature in TeamViewer do?

Tags: teamviewer

What does the "Grant easy access" feature in TeamViewer do? I can't find the documentation for it anywhere.

[image]

Comment: http://downloadus1.teamviewer.com/docs/en/v10/TeamViewer10-Manual-Remote-Control-en.pdf - page 30.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

#### What does the "Grant easy access" feature in TeamViewer do?

"Grant easy access" is used to allow connections to your own computers without using a password.

---

#### Connections to your own computers without a password.

> For this mode, it is not necessary to define a password for access. Consequently, when establishing a connection, it is not necessary to enter a password, if you are connecting to one of your own devices with your TeamViewer account.
>
> **If activated, access to the computer is only possible in the following
>   cases:**
>
> - Easy access without password is only possible with your TeamViewer account.
> - For other connections the TeamViewer ID and the password of the device are required.
> - If in the TeamViewer settings you deactivate the random or personal password, you, and only you, have access to the device via your
>     TeamViewer account.
>
> **To activate easy access to a computer, proceed as follows:**
>
> 1. Start TeamViewer on the computer.
> 2. Log in to the Computers & Contacts list with your TeamViewer account
> 3. Click Tools | Options.
> 4. Select the Security tab.
>
>    - If the device is already assigned to your account, under Personal Password (for unattended access) select the checkbox Grant easy access.
>    - If the device is not yet assigned to your account, click the Configure... button. The Assign to account dialog box will open.
>
>      1. Click the Assign button.
>      2. Under Personal Password (for unattended access) activate the Grant  easy access checkbox.
> 5. Click the OK button.
> 6. You have activated easy access for this device.

Source [TeamViewer 10 Manual Remote Control](http://downloadeu2.teamviewer.com/docs/en/v10/TeamViewer10-Manual-Remote-Control-en.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

It lets you set up an account that the computer is then associated with. You can then see computers on that account that are online, and simply double click on it to connect to it.

> You can activate easy access for a device in TeamViewer full version
> settings.
>
> If activated, access to the computer is only possible in the
> following cases:
>
> Easy access without password is only possible with
> your TeamViewer account.
>
> For other connections the TeamViewer ID and
> the password of the device are required.
>
> If in the TeamViewer
> settings you deactivate the random or personal password, you, and only
> you, have access to the device via your TeamViewer account.

In the manual [here](https://dl.tvcdn.de/docs/en/v12/TeamViewer12-Manual-Remote-Control-en.pdf).  *Note: this is the direct download link that will immediately download the manual.*